# Abstract logic question , scrapy - scrape then pass data to another site in one project

Tags: scrapy, logic

New to scrapy. < 72hrs. A little confused.

I have two sites i wish to **scrape**. Site1, Site2.
Have successfully scraped Site 1, and extracted the data I wish to use this data and start scraping site2 only after site1 has been scraped.

Simple example would be something like
Get all CAR-MODEL-YR-PRICE from cars.for.sale (SITE1)
Use this data to compare on ebay.com (SITE2) USING SITE1 CAR-MODEL-YR-PRICE

what is happening in my inital trails.
I start scraping both websites at the same time (it appears) but site2 returns nothing as it appears to not have the site1 data

Do I need to run 2 spiders

I looked at the scrapy documentation,

```
def parse()
 ...scrape site1
 ...format the data
 yield (... , callback=parse2)

def parse2()
 ...with data from site1
 ...scrape site2
```

but nothing seems to be working. (lack of understanding, or misunderstanding how things work)

Can anybody post a template of a good starting of point with how to scape site1 THEN with data **scrape** site 2

.

Comment: Your pseudo code seems correct, assuming it looks more like [Umair’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54476560/939364). Could you share the actual code you are using and explain what unexpected thing is happening?

Comment: fyi it's __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

You have `meta` key which you can pass across requests

```
def parse()
 ...scrape site1
 ...format the data
 some_data = {'hello': "man"}
 yield (... , callback=parse2, meta={'data': some_data })

def parse2()
 ...with data from site1
 some_data = response.meta['data']
 ...scrape site2
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward but simple **pipeline** would be to create 2 spiders inside the same project (checkout the command [`genspider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#genspider) for this).

Having done that, and successfully implemented the first spider, you need to store the data. Use the command line for this or just built-in Python libraries to store your data as you please (json, csv, ...).

Finally, use Python to read the file in your spider 2 and now you have the data inside your second spider and you can do whatever you please with it.]

P.S. This is a simple and kind of naive approach, but it just works! If you want to do some more complex stuff, like executing everything inside a single Python script you could check out this link to the best practices of Scrapy: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html. But as a beginner (<72 hours) I would not worry too much.

P.S.S. Good luck scraping the world! But do not overheat their servers ;)!

Comment: Take into account this is an **alternative** approach to what you proposed on your question: but doing everything inside the same spider could work, is just better to separate your parsing functions by URL since, technically, each spider does the same parsing process FOR EACH url in the `start_url` class attribute. I hope I made myself clear and this did not confuse you.